Environment variable not updating in Node.js (Express + TypeScript)
I have a Node.js project with Express and TypeScript that uses environment variables. One of my services (AIVoiceStreamService) reads ELEVENLABS_API_KEY from the .env file. However, the console output always shows an outdated value for the key, even though I have updated the .env file with a new value.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
class AIVoiceStreamService {
  private openai: OpenAI;
  private elevenlabsApiKey: string;

  constructor() {
    if (!process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY) {
      throw new Error('Missing OpenAI API Key');
    }
    if (!process.env.ELEVENLABS_API_KEY) {
      throw new Error('Missing ElevenLabs API Key');
    }

    this.openai = new OpenAI({
      apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
    });
    this.elevenlabsApiKey = process.env.ELEVENLABS_API_KEY;
  }

  async generateVoiceStream(
    messages: ChatMessage[],
    res: Response,
    context: string,
    options: AIVoiceStreamOptions = {}
  ): Promise<void> {
    const {
      openaiModel = 'gpt-4o-mini',
      stability = 0.75,
      similarityBoost = 0.85,
      voiceId = "Xb7hH8MSUJpSbSDYk0k2" // Default voice ID
    } = options;

    console.log(this.elevenlabsApiKey);
    console.log(process.env.ELEVENLABS_API_KEY);
  }
}

Output in console:
Server running on port 3000
Connected to MongoDB
sk_025a5b*********************************491b16ce4
sk_025a5b*********************************491b16ce4

.env file content:
ELEVENLABS_API_KEY=sk_3e7b862579*******************************58177aac

package.json:
{
  "name": "ai_be",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "tsc": "tsc -b && nodemon"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^22.10.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.9",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.4.7",
    "express": "^4.21.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.9.1",
    "openai": "^4.77.0"
  }
}

I've Tried:

Updating the .env file.
Deleting the dist and node_modules folders.
Reinstalling dependencies using npm install.
Confirming the .env file is in the root directory.
Dotenv is imported and configured perfectly

Environment:

Node.js: v18.17.1
OS: Windows 11

What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure the updated .env value is picked up in my application?

You don't show how (if at all) dotenv is actually being used here. Please give a [mre]. What does a plain node -p 'process.env.ELEVENLABS_API_KEY' show?

@jonrsharpe getting the wrong variable
(base) asvinir@Asvinis-MacBook-Air ai_be % node -p 'process.env.ELEVENLABS_API_KEY'
sk_025a5b43c**********************50d491b16ce4

dotenv won't override actual system env vars, by default. Read the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv
